# MPlayerX controls at top of window

Tags: macos

The MPlayerX (latest version, 1.0.22.1) video controls used to be at the bottom of the window, where they were easily accessible. Some time ago (on the order of weeks or months), despite MPlayerX not having changed, the video controls have changed to go at the top somehow. There, they are partly obscured by the title bar. I know I can turn the title bar off, but I rather want the controls to go back on the bottom of the window...

So far I've tried just restarting MPlayerX as well as removing the preferences associated within my user account (by removing org.niltsh.* files from ~/Library/Preferences). Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you drag the controls into another Position? If i do that, they stay at the new position.

Comment: I don't use MPlayer, but in VLC player I can drag the play controls to a position on the full screen and it stays there. Then stooping movig the cursor it makes it vanish.